# Installing all python modules

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-2, pip

I'm going on vacation into a foreign country and I want to take my Pi 2 with me to play a bit, not having a particular project in mind. I may not have Internet access all the time or it may be limited to a few 100 MB or has a limited band-width.

While I might be able to google for answers, I don't want to download and install large amounts of data.

Is there a way I can install all python modules, so whatever code example I'll find I have at least the module already installed on my Pi?

I can install single modules with e.g.

```
sudo pip install abjad
```

and I'm looking for

```
sudo pip install *
```

as well as getting a rough idea how much disk space this would need. At the moment I have a 16 GB SD card, but I could switch to a 64 GB disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked on Raspbian Jessie, which was the most recent release at the time of writing.

Due to some [PIP issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341064/how-do-i-fix-importerror-cannot-import-name-incompleteread), fix that first

```
sudo apt-get remove python-pip
sudo easy_install3 -U pip
```

For some of the following installations, I also needed to install their dependencies:

```
# for lxml
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
# for abjad
sudo apt-get install lilypond
# For pygtk
sudo apt-get install python-gtk2
# for pyfirmata
sudo apt-get install python-serial
sudo apt-get install arduino
sudo apt-get install python-scipy
```

It seems there are many interesting modules that I'll need during my trip. Some of them were already installed

```
# already installed
sudo pip install -U rpi.gpio
sudo pip install -U simplejson
# already installed
sudo pip install -U requests
sudo pip install -U lxml
sudo pip install -U nose
sudo pip install -U colorama
sudo pip install -U selenium
sudo pip install -U numpy
sudo pip install -U abjad
sudo pip install -U matplotlib
sudo pip install -U formlayout
```

And for some Arduino-Shield experiments:

```
sudo pip install -U pyfirmata
```

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, you cannot install all the Python modules with a single command. The py packages are roughly millions. Depending on your project you can install your desired packages.

I recommend you install some basic and important packages for almost any project.

1. numpy

`sudo pip install numpy`

2. scipy

`sudo pip install scipy`

3. matplotlib

`sudo pip install matplotlib`

4. pandas

`sudo pip install pandas`

5. sklearn

`sudo pip install sklearn`

6. opencv (for image processing)

`I prefer compiling and building it instead of installing the defaults`

7. RPI.GPIO

`sudo pip install rpi.gpio`

Those you will always use in any project you want.

The 16 GB SD card is excellent for a Pi. I think 64 GB will make your Pi become slower. Remember the Pi is a mini-PC not a real desktop. The speed will always be a headache.

Last thing to mention, always use a 2A 5V Adapter as the peripherals are current hungry. Sometimes if the peripherals don't get enough current, the Pi shuts down as a short-circuit protection.

Hope I helped.

Comment: Technically I can't follow how a 64 GB SD card will make the Raspberry slow. I'm also missing a package for GPIO in your list

Comment: GPIO package is usually installed with sudo apt-get update or sudo apt-get install python-dev

Comment: @ThomasWeller If you put your Raspbian img on a 8 or 16GB SD card, you will notice a little bit increase in speed rather than on 64GB one.

Comment: @ThomasWeller if my answer is convenient, please consider accepting it.

Comment: @OsamaAbbas: -1 for the second to last paragraph. The size of the SD card won't impact the RPi's performance at all.

Comment: @Jacobm001 I faced this problem when I changed to 32GB from 8GB. The speed then was lowered a little bit

Comment: Wait, first you said going from a smaller to a bigger card slowed it down. Now you're claiming a smaller card is slower? Both are incorrect. Your speeds will be limited by the type of card, not the capacity.

Comment: @Jacobm001 Sorry I mistyped changing from 8GB to 32GB. Sorry my mistake. Trust me both were the same, class 4 kingston cards. It's a personal experience. Unfortunately, my country doesn't have even class 6 SD cards, and if you find it, it will be super duper expensive.